# My Linear Search Is not returning any index

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-search

I am writing a simple linear search program. But it does not return any index that I search for even though I have specified it to print the index when the user searches for an item in the list:

```
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
tv = input("Search index:")

def LinearSearch():
    for i in range(0,len(list)):
        if list[i] == tv:
            print("Found at index ", i)

LinearSearch()
```

Comment: Does it not _print_ or not _return_ a result? Also, is this Python 2 or Python 3? Because, depending on which it is, `tv` might be an `int` or `str`.

Comment: it does not "print" and it is in Python 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tv = input("Search index:")
```

results in `tv` being a string, so comparison with an int will not work. You will need to convert `tv` to an int:

```
tv = int(input("Search index:"))
```